# What is a HD Webcam?

Tags: webcam, hdvideo

It seems like a stupid question, but really what is the difference between a webcam and a HD webcam?

There are several webcams that can do 1280x786 or more, so what makes HD webcams HD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All High Definition (HD) means is that it is "720p" or more.  This just means there are at least 720 horizontal lines of resolution.  Anything with a resolution of 1280x786 is automatically considered HD, because it has 786 horizontal lines of resolution.

A lot of products, like computer monitors, have been made for many years at resolutions higher than 720p, but the term HD wasn't used until they started selling TV's at above normal broadcast resolution (TV signals used to all be 480p).  Now they sell a lot of stuff with the HD label, even though it has been HD all along by the definition.

Summary: Ignore the "HD" and just look at the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it comes with 2mp camera and be able to record HD video (and "HD" means a good camera (carl zeiss for example) here.)

But its really "as far as I know", fix me if thats not the case.